# Eloquent returning extra records

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, restler

I've defined a model for Eloquent like this:

```php
<?php

class Order extends Eloquent {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['station_id', 'created', 'due', 'month', 'comments', 'name', 'ud', 'dp', 'swrv', 'sh', 'jmsw', 'sw', 'prrv', 'mhsw', 'bmsw', 'mp', 'pr', 'st', 'total_points'];
}

?>
```

So there are 19 columns listed in the fillable array.  When I call `Order::find($id)` and return that from a restler method the encoded JSON object has all my fillable columns with their proper values AND 20 extras where the key is the index, so station_id is listed under a 1 key, created is listed under a 2 key, etc...

How do I make it not return those numbered values and just use the $fillable values?

Comment: It's not Eloquent thing, right? I don't know Restler, but check how this works, because Laravel is not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong!

`fillable` property is for whitelisting what can be filled up by supplying an array of data

for avoiding few fields from being returned in the output, you can use `hidden` property instead to provide a blacklist.

Starting from Laravel 4.2.8 you can specify an white list with `visible` property as shown below.

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['station_id', 'created', 'due', 'month', 'comments', 'name', 'ud', 'dp', 'swrv', 'sh', 'jmsw', 'sw', 'prrv', 'mhsw', 'bmsw', 'mp', 'pr', 'st', 'total_points'];
    protected $visible = ['station_id', 'created', 'due', 'month', 'comments', 'name', 'ud', 'dp', 'swrv', 'sh', 'jmsw', 'sw', 'prrv', 'mhsw', 'bmsw', 'mp', 'pr', 'st', 'total_points'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks much.  The $fillable is still kinda confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that what columns you want to retrieve from database in model by using below code.

```
public function profile() {
  return $this->belongs_to('profile')->select(array('id', 'profilename'));
}
```